# Unique index between int and string

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I've got this issue where I want to create a unique index between an integer and a string, but it's giving me the following issue. How can I make this work and why is this not allowed? Because I actually really want this unique combination, to make sure no double labels are stored in the database.

> Column 'Label' in table 'dbo.HostingReportGroups' is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index.

The model that I use for this is the following:

```
public class HostingReportGroup
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Index("UniqueCustomerAndLabel", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    [Index("UniqueCustomerAndLabel", 2, IsUnique = true)]
    public string Label { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<HostingReportGroupList> HostingReportGroupLists { get; set; }
}
```

And the migration that I'm trying to execute contains the following code:

```
public partial class adding_unique_key_to_hosting_report_group : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateIndex("dbo.HostingReportGroups", new[] { "CustomerId", "Label" }, unique: true, name: "UniqueCustomerAndLabel");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropIndex("dbo.HostingReportGroups", "UniqueCustomerAndLabel");
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess the C#  string is translated as `NVARCHAR(MAX)` Try to add max size for example up to 500. `[MaxLength(500)]`

Comment: @lad2025 You were totally right.. Why is it that you can't assign it to a nvarchar(max), do you have any idea?

Comment: @Jordy because it would take a long time to ensure that values are unique. nvarchar(max) can be very long text

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C# string data type is translated as `NVARCHAR(MAX)` in T-SQL. SQL Server has limitation:

> [CREATE INDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
>
> The maximum allowable size of the combined index values is 900 bytes for a clustered index, or 1,700 for a nonclustered index.
>
> Columns that are of the large object (LOB) data types ntext, text, **varchar(max), nvarchar(max)**, varbinary(max), xml, or image cannot be specified as key columns for an index

So you need to define max size(using annotation):

```
[MaxLength(500)]
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=644701118651de64bd4d51b43e494440)**